# 'No Space Left on Device' when creating Semaphore?

Tags: python, macos, filesystems, multiprocessing

I have recently started observing the following error with Python on a Macbook Pro (OS X 10.10). According to the disk utility, about one half of the 120 GB SSD drive remains available, so I suspect this is related not do disk but to some other filesystem property?

What factors control the amount of space available for semaphores? What can I do to fix this problem?

```
$ python -c 'import multiprocessing; multiprocessing.Semaphore()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rmcgibbo/miniconda/envs/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 81, in Semaphore
    return Semaphore(value, ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/Users/rmcgibbo/miniconda/envs/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 127, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, value, SEM_VALUE_MAX, ctx=ctx)
  File "/Users/rmcgibbo/miniconda/envs/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 60, in __init__
    unlink_now)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

(Note, this doesn't appear to depend on the version of python. Same error with 2.7.9)

Answer (score 3):

According to [MacOSX manuals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html), the `sem_open` system call used to create a semaphore can fail with ENOSPC:

> ```
>  [ENOSPC]           O_CREAT is specified, the file does not exist, and
>                     there is insufficient space available to create the
>                     semaphore.
> ```

I suggest you use `dtruss` to find out where Python tries to create this semaphore.

Comment: I can track in the python source code the place that the semaphore is created, but it's not clear to me how to use that information to debug the problem.  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7688b44387d116522ff53c0927169db45969f0e/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#L445

Comment: Use the [`dtruss`](http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/dtruss_example.txt) command to see the actual `sem_open` system call arguments.

Comment: I think it's (not too familar with dtrace) `23646/0x95e569:  sem_open(0x101B54D60, 0xA00, 0x180)   = -1 Err#28`

Comment: Yes it is that, but does not seem to display the filename, only the address of filename (should be the first argument).

Comment: Hmm, I guess you need to copy the dtruss script and modify it a bit, after the line that has `syscall::open*:return,`, make a similar line for `sem_open` to see the arguments

Comment: The string at that first argument is "/mp24003-4"

Answer (score 2):

Old post but for me the culprit was the tmpfs partition /dev/shm which was full.

**Solution**: increase its size (https://www.golinuxcloud.com/change-tmpfs-partition-size-redhat-linux/) or release some space.